# Using React hooks to prevent React re-rendering of a D3 chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I have been using React and D3 separately and now have a project where I need low level control over the plotting function of an application. Basically, I need to be able to go and fetch higher resolution data from a database as the user zooms in, and vice versa as the user zooms out, on a plot.

I have found a few methods to use D3 and React together. I wanted to try and keep all of my React code based around the hooks API as that is what is used for the rest of the code base. I am struggling to get the hooks equivalent for the specific cases that I am facing. The documentation on React hooks is great but I think my situation is  more of an edge case and I have not seen any discussion relating to similar use cases to what I have.

The logic of the code is fairly straight forward: 
I have a main container, call it App.js, that hold some state. App.js renders a Wrapper component (which is where the challenge is occurring) and then  the Wrapper.js file simply creates the D3 Plot. The D3 plot is just typical D3 code for a line plot with some zoom events.

The Wrapper code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Plot from './Plot'; // D3 plot

class Wrapper extends Component {

    // Sets up plot when Wrapper first added to DOM tree
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            plot: new Plot(this.refs.plot, this.props.data, this.props.updateData)
        });
    };

    // Do not allow React to re-render the Wrapper and therefore the Plot
    shouldComponentUpdate(){
        return false;
    };

    // When the data prop changes, execute the update() method in the plot file
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.state.plot.update(nextProps.data) // the .update() method calls props.updateData()
    }

    render(){
        return <div ref="plot"></div>
    }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

I have started putting together the hooks version below but I cannot come up with suitable emthods that meet the specific requirements of what I am after for the cases of the shouldComponentUpdate and componentWIllReceiveProps blocks.

hooks version:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Plot from './Plot'; // D3 plot

const Wrapper = props => {

    // destruct props
    const { 
        data = props.data,
        fields = props.fields,
        click = props.click
    } = props

    // initialise empty ref
    const plotRef= useRef(null);

    // ComponentDidMount translated to hooks
    useEffect(() => {
        new Plot(plotRef, data, updateData)
    },[]) // empty array ensures the plot object is only created once on initial mounting

    // shouldComponentUpdate
    useEffect(...) // This won't work because render has already occurred before useEffect dependency array diffed?

    // ComponentWIllReceiveProps
    useEffect(() => {
        plot.update(data)
    }, [data]) // This won't work because component needs to have re-rendered

    return (
        <div ref= {plotRef}></div>
    )


};

export default Wrapper;
```

What I am trying to achieve is blocking any rendering of the D3 chart after the initial mount, but then if the data props changes in the parent component, execute a method in the  D3 class without allowing React to re-render the Wrapper component.

Is this at all possible or am I better off leaving this as a class based component?

I have been banging my head against a  wall trying to get the logic without any success so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your return value in React useMemo with suitable dependencies.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: thanks for the response. do you mean to wrap the Wrapper in useMemo and then  just have a blank dependency array to avoid re-renders? In that case I wonder if React.Memo is a better choice?

Comment: yeah but you told you want to run some function on rerender. If you use React.memo the entire component will not be called. If you use useMemo only the thing in that will not be called and all the other functions are called.