# Render a stateful, class component instance inside a function component

Tags: reactjs

I tried to search for this and I think the answer is being obfuscated by many questions and tutorials using similar keywords - but not with the specific issue I'm having. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59302794/using-react-hooks-to-prevent-react-re-rendering-of-a-d3-chart) issue is close - where a complex component (D3) is continuously being re-rendered. Lots of answers I find are for memoize and PureComponents - these don't work for d3, Google Maps, etc though  - the rendering of `Stateful_Class_Component_Widget` happens without fail.

I have a React app with a structure similar to the following (very basic sample of general structure)

```
// big stateful component running everything with state
class AppView extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        documents: [] // array of simple JSON docs fetched from API
        show_widget: true 
      }
      this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this)
      // more involved functions, set states, etc
      render()
         return (
         <div>
         <StatelessFC1
              documents = {this.state.documents}
              show_widget = {this.state.show_widget}

         />
         <StatelessFC2
              props={this.state.otherStateThing}
         />
         </div>
         )
}

class Stateful_Class_Component_Widget  extends React.Component {
   // assume D3, Google Maps, Leaflet - a big involved 
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log("New instance")
      this.state = {
        documents: [] // array of simple JSON docs fetched from API 
      }
   }
      // some functions etc
   render() {
     return (
      <div id="d3_uses_me">
      // d3/google maps code
      </div>
     )
   }

const StatelessFC1 = (props) =>
 return (
   <StatelessFC1_a 
     documents={props.documents}
     show_widget = {props.show_widget}
   />
 )

const StatelessFC1_a = (props) =>
 return (
   <StatelessFC1_a_i
       documents={props.documents}
       show_widget = {props.show_widget}
   />
// this only renders when AppView's state is 'show-widget') 
const StatelessFC1_a_i = (props) =>
  return (
    { props.show_widget &&
       <Stateful_Class_Component_Widget 
          documents={props.documents}
       />
    }
    </div>)
```

So the idea is that in order to structure the application view, I have a function of dumb stateless components that get rerendered as necessary when the AppView state changes - all good there. State for everything else is handled fine by the AppView.

The problem is though - is that the `Stateful_Class_Component_Widget` (in my case it is a similar to a google map - so re-rendering it each time something trivial changes is pointless) keeps getting re-created - that is each time the state of AppView changes, a new instance of the Stateful_Class_Component_Widget is being created (likely because of the re-rendering triggered in its 'parent' stateless components  - which is quite taxing since this is a third party API. Ideally it should only update when *its* state/props change - which is all good - but right now it is being created everytime AppView's state changes (can see that "new instance" in console each time)

Essentially I want one instance of the `Stateful_Class_Component_Widget` and want it to remain persistent (though not always visible) throughout the course of the application lifetime. Right now it is always being reconstructed. Is only way to do it to bring it directly into AppView?

Comment: Your issue is about only re-render when state/props changes which means a proper diff check, and I suppose you may need `pureComponent` and `immutable` to do it.

Comment: Tacking on a recommendational use of the [`memo` HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). They say it's for functional components, but you can wrap any react component. It "turns" components into pure components, with an optional second parameter equality (prop comparison) function. You can wrap the google map component and pass a comparison function to trigger when you want it to rerender.